# system function not working as expected in c

Tags: c, linux, driver

```
#include <linux/input-event-codes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/input.h>

#define MOUSEFILE "/dev/input/event9"
//#define TOUCHPAD "/dev/input/event0"

void createSpot(){
    system("gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme Spotlight");
}

void offSpot(){
    system("gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme Adwaita");
}

int main()
{
    int fd;
    struct input_event ie;

    if((fd = open(MOUSEFILE, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        perror("opening device");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(read(fd, &ie, sizeof(struct input_event))) {
        if(ie.value==120){
          createSpot(); 
        }
        if(ie.value==-120){
          offSpot();
        }
        printf("time %ld.%06ld\ttype %d\tcode %d\tvalue %d\n",
               ie.time.tv_sec, ie.time.tv_usec, ie.type, ie.code, ie.value);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to get the input from mouse of scrollup to activate highlighter cursor but it is not working as expected. I tried everything to make it work.It work fine if i create a separate file to run this command only but in my case it it to be activated if and only if mouse is scrolled

Comment: Tag only the language in which the code is written in. And this is `c`

Comment: can anyone really helpme with this

Comment: And the command they works fine in terminal

Comment: Are you seeing the expected `ie.value` in the `printf` output?

Comment: yes , also the createSpot function is being called when scrolled up

Comment: I found the reason it's cause that command doesn't work with sudo user but to run program i have to run executable as sudoer does anyone help me with that